# vba excel 2010 Environ("username") not working in saveas filepath

Tags: vba, excel-2010

For some reason I can get the Message Box to tell me what the username is, but it doesn't work the same way within the save as path.  I get a "Cannot find path" error.

Not sure how to fix this.  I've also looked at references, and they seem like they are correct.

If I change the path to include the actual username per computer, the macro works fine.  But I need this to be a global macro for any computer/user.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub SAVEAS_2010()
'
' SAVEAS_2010 Macro
MsgBox Environ("username")

Dim UserName As String
UserName = Environ("username")

ChDir "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Dropbox\Open Machine Schedule"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
    "C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Dropbox\Open Machine Schedule\Open Machine Schedule - Current_2.xlsx" _
    , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: I've also tried just putting the Environ("username") into the path with no luck. I still get the same error- cannot find path.

Comment: What does `Debug.Print Dir("C:\Users\" & UserName & "\Dropbox\Open Machine Schedule", vbDirectory)` give you?

Comment: Sorry one of my variable was mismatched.  I ran the Debug.Print again and it doesn't print anything.  I just get the same run-time 76 error Path not found.  Then it highlights the ChDir line when I choose to Debug. Same as before.

Comment: Everything points to that directory not existing...

Comment: But it does exist.  Like I said when I change the " & UserName & " to the actual username of the person logged in for example ~\Users\John Smith\Dropbox\Open Machine Schedule" it works fine.  That's my whole confusion, this was a recorded macro and the only thing I changed was the Environ("username") portion.

Comment: does it work without the `ChDir` line? that's not really required if you're passing the full path to `SaveAs`

Comment: It works with the ChDir line removed and with John Smith(actual username) in the filepath. Otherwise it presents the same error.

Comment: It's possible that `Environ("username")` isn't returning the value you expect (although it may appear to be the same, there could be some subtle difference) How about trying `Debug.print Environ("username") = "John Smith"` ?

Answer (score 6):

Or you could just put `VBA.` in front of it. This fixes it for me.
i.e. `Environ("Username")` becomes `VBA.Environ("Username")`.

Answer (score 5):

Seems an old question. But for anyone who stumble on this post, adding **$** worked for me -
**& Environ$("username") &**

Answer (score 2):

```
Environ("UserProfile") &
```

This is what worked for me on 2007-2013 Excel versions.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the same problem using VBA 7.1

Solution is to use

```
    path = Environ$("Userprofile") & "\Documents\temp_excel_files\"
```

---

```
    Environ$("Userprofile")
```

Will give you something like "c:\users\Johnsmith" to put into your path.

Cheers!
Andrew

Comment: When I execute `Environ` in the Immediate window, it works.  However, it fails when running in a procedure.  Why does adding $ fix the issue?